# Text-to-Speech in Raspberry Pi using gTTS

Tags: pi-3, text-to-speech

So, I've been using Google Assistant on my Raspberry Pi 3 to make a sort of home assistant. The speech recognition works perfectly with Google Assistant and I'm able to say my commands and convert them to text.

For Text to Speech, I've been using, gTTS with my own commands. So, I feed the gTTS with my own lines and it converts it to an mp3 file and plays it. However, it being an online service, it seems to take a couple of seconds to convert. Around 8-9 to be exact. I was wondering if there was any way of reducing that time, as it seems to be a huge gap of me waiting there for the text to convert. I've tried using other TTS services such as espeak but do not find their voice appealing.

I've been using  pretty basic code for gTTS, just for calling it and saving the file
import os
from gtts import gTTS

```
import sys
def speak(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts = gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save("audio.mp3")
    os.system("mpg321 -q  audio.mp3")


if (len(sys.argv)>=1):
    if (sys.argv[1] !=""):
        speak(sys.argv[1])
    else: 
        print ("No arguments found")
else: 
    print ("No Url path found")
```

Comment: If you try using the [command-line tool](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/) for gTTS (`gtts-cli 'hello' --output hello.mp3`), does that take long or not? If it does, I'd look at networking being the problem, otherwise if that command is fairly fast it's something else.

Comment: @Aurora0001, it looks to be taking the same amount of time. Guess its my network speed that's the problem.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to gTTS I can use?

Comment: Are all network requests slow on your Pi, or does it just look to be Google's text to speech? Perhaps try loading up a web browser and testing to see how fast pages load to see if it is *all* requests or just gTTS that has network issues.

Comment: @Aurora0001, I'm pretty sure loading a web page on the Chromium is a little faster if not the same speed. I think that my network speed is the problem. I'm going to have to find an alternative to gTTS that works faster.